# How to run a cancellable function when a new Tkinter window opens

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

In tkinter, I would like to create the following:

When the button foo is pressed, the function foo begins running immediately. A new window will pop up with a a "cancel" button that lets the user terminate the process midway through (as my actual process can take up to 30 minutes). If foo runs to completion, the window closes itself and notifies the user that the process completed.

Here is code that demonstrates my toy problem:

```
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, Toplevel, Tk
import time
import multiprocessing

def foo():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.1)

class TerminatedProcess(Exception):
    def __init__(self, str = "Process was terminated"):
        self.error_str = str

class ProcessWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, process):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self. process = process

        terminate_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=self.cancel)
        terminate_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.grab_set() # so you can't push submit multiple times

    def cancel(self):
        self.process.terminate()
        self.destroy()
        raise TerminatedProcess

    def launch(self):
        self.process.start()
        self.process.join()
        self.destroy()

class MainApplication(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text = "foo", command = self.callback)
        self.button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def callback(self):
        try:
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
            process_window = ProcessWindow(self, proc)
            process_window.launch()
        except TerminatedProcess as e: # raised if foo is cancelled in other window
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Cancelled", message=e.error_str)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(message="sucessful run", title="Finished")

def main():
    root = Tk()
    my_app = MainApplication(root, padding=(4))
    my_app.grid(column=0, row=0)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With this code, when the button foo is pressed, process_window is indeed made because the the function foo runs, and I get a "run successful" dialogue box, but the  window never pops up! This is a problem because the user needs to have the option of terminating foo. Interestingly enough, If I delete process_window.launch(), I will still get the "run successful" message (as expected), but the process_window shows up.

I have tried putting the launch command inside the initialization, but that made the window not show up, either.

I also tried starting the process outside the window declaration as follows:

```
proc.start()
process_window = ProcessWindow(self, proc)
proc.join()
```

The window still failed to show up, but the process ran.

My question is, how do I need to arrange these pieces to generate the ProcessWindow AND automatically start the process when the ProcessWindow opens?

UPDATE (workaround): I am aware that I could create a start button inside the ProcessWindow that would run the function (and then disable the button after it had been pressed once), but I would still like to know how to implement what was described in the original question.

Comment: you may consider reading our help section on making a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I would either have to implement a lot of work-around code to test this and filter out a lot of irrelevant code to understand the root problem.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks for the heads up. In this new edit, most of the code (main, foo, the TerminateProcess exception) can be ignored but was included to be runnable, and everything that was nonessential was taken out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, Toplevel, Tk
import time
import multiprocessing

def foo():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.1)

class ProcessWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, process):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.process = process

        terminate_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=self.cancel)
        terminate_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.grab_set() # so you can't push submit multiple times

    def cancel(self):
        self.process.terminate()
        self.destroy()
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Cancelled", message='Process was terminated')

    def launch(self):
        self.process.start()
        self.after(10, self.isAlive)            # Starting the loop to check when the process is going to end

    def isAlive(self):
        if self.process.is_alive():                     # Process still running
            self.after(100, self.isAlive)               # Going again...
        elif self:
            # Process finished
            messagebox.showinfo(message="sucessful run", title="Finished")
            self.destroy()

class MainApplication(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text = "foo", command = self.callback)
        self.button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def callback(self):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
        process_window = ProcessWindow(self, proc)
        process_window.launch()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    my_app = MainApplication(root, padding=(4))
    my_app.grid(column=0, row=0)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!